# Is my training working for me

Tags: heart-rate

I am finding that my hard runs (5.31min/km) my avg HR is around 160, but I am not running to exhaustion by any means, and recover pretty well after 10min rest or so.  Usually use a harder negative split (5.15 min/km) for last 2 km.

Am i running too hard for my age? Should I back off my training?

1. 60yr old male - fairly unfit 12 months ago - 91kg, 172cm
2. started walking/jogging and reducing calorie intake
3. Introduced running 6mnths ago - around 15km/week
4. Added gym (stretches/weights/rowing) 3 months ago, around a 55min session -4/week
5. increasing running (3xweek) up to 25km/week

Currently working as 4x per week at gym (55 mins) and 3x per week running (up to 25km total)

I am now down to 78kg, and resting HR is around 64bpm (via fitbit)

I aim for one hard run/week (7km), one longer run (60 minutes), and one easier run 7km in around 45minutes

Comment: There are a few close votes as being primarily opinion based. I think if you narrowed your focus a bit, as "Is my training working" is a bit vague. Working for...what? What are your goals? What do you want to achieve? If you could add those in, people could assess your workout regimen against those goals.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, well done! That is great progress over 12 months. Welcome to Physical Fitness SE.

Whether you should continue to train at your current rate is entirely down to your body. You need to listen to your body and understand if it needs more food/rest to keep up with the exercise you are doing.

I know a few ultra marathon runners in their late 50s, early 60s so arbitrarily saying that "at X age, you should only do X exercise" is rubbish. You should set some goals and work to achieve them, it will help you sustain and celebrate your success. It may be beneficial to check with your GP (Doctor) if your goals are suitable.

Summing up, listen to your body. If you are getting enough sleep and eating enough food and you are still struggling to recover then consider reducing the frequency of your exercise (never the volume/duration!). ALWAYS give yourself at least 1 rest day a week.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your training is working well for you.

Building up to your current routine over 12 months is not overdoing it, provided the following is true:

- You're still able to sleep well
- You don't feel constantly hungry
- Your eating habits aren't out of control; that is, you don't feel urges to drastically overeat
- You don't dread your workouts
- You're not sacrificing important things to fit your workouts in
- You feel generally healthy and happy during your chosen activity